# Problem in settings the GitHub codespace first time

Tags: javascript, git, github, codespaces, github-codespaces

I am setting my GitHub for the first time I run the JavaScript code first time in Codespace and the code is simply `console.log("hello");` but it shows permission denied then I run the command `chmod u+x "file path"` and run again then it shows "syntax error near unexpected token "hello".

I tried to search online but get nothing.

Comment: How are you running it? Which files does the project contain? What makes you think you can run it they way you are running it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: please remove git tag. This has absolutely nothing to do with the usage of git.

Answer (score 0):

If Node.js is installed in your Codespace, a simple `node "file path"` should be enough.

Adding a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) to your JavaScript file can help if you want to run the file directly as an executable. A shebang is a special line at the beginning of a script that tells the system which interpreter to use for running the script.

Add the following shebang line at the very beginning of your JavaScript file:

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

Your file should now look like this:

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node
console.log("hello");
```

Make the file executable by adding the execute permission: `chmod +x "file path"`, as you did in your question.

Run the file directly as an executable:

```
./"file path"
```

With the shebang added, the system will know to use the Node.js interpreter to run your JavaScript file, and you should see the "`hello`" output in the console.

Keep in mind that using a shebang is not necessary if you are running your JavaScript files using the `node` command.
It is mainly useful when you want to create executable scripts that can be run directly from the command line.

See also "[Configuring your Linux terminal on GitHub Codespaces](https://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/codespaces-terminal/)" from [Bea Stollnitz](https://bea.stollnitz.com/) for more.